# Unable to establish correct parent-child relationship in sql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

The problem:

SQLAlchemy model code for parent-child relationships is not being created as expected by [SQLacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen).

My workflow:

[image: ER diagram of tables]

In the ER diagram, `product` is the parent table, `feature` and `related` are child tables. The relationship between product and feature is supposed to be many-to-many, as is the relationship between product and related.

Excerpt of what I want the `Product` class to look like:

```py
class Product():
    relateds = relationship('Related', secondary='product_related')
    features = relationship('Feature', secondary='product_featured')
```

Excerpt of what SQLacodegen does:

```py
class Product():
    relateds = relationship('Related', secondary='product_related')
    # features is missing

class Feature():
   # products appears here, making Feature the parent of Product
   # when it should be the other way round
   products = relationship('Product', secondary='product_features')
```

Original SQL code for the tables:

```sql
-- Table: product
CREATE TABLE product (
    id bigserial  NOT NULL,
    mpn text  NULL,
    title text  NULL,
    price real  NULL,
    msrp real  NULL,
    stock_availability boolean  NULL,
    country_id int8  NULL,
    description text  NULL,
    weight_packaging real  NULL,
    item_type varchar(20)  NULL,
    upc varchar(40)  NULL,
    model varchar(60)  NULL,
    sku varchar(40)  NULL,
    badges text  NULL,
    url text  NULL,
    site_item_id text  NULL,
    brand_id int8  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX country_id on product (country_id ASC);

CREATE INDEX product_idx_2 on product (brand_id ASC);


-- Table: related
CREATE TABLE related (
    id bigserial  NOT NULL,
    name text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT related_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Table: product_related
CREATE TABLE product_related (
    product_id int8  NOT NULL,
    related_id int8  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_related_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id,related_id)
);

CREATE INDEX product_related_idx_1 on product_related (product_id ASC);

CREATE INDEX product_related_idx_2 on product_related (related_id ASC);

-- Reference: product_related_related (table: product_related)
ALTER TABLE product_related ADD CONSTRAINT product_related_related
    FOREIGN KEY (related_id)
    REFERENCES related (id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;

-- Reference: product_related_product (table: product_related)
ALTER TABLE product_related ADD CONSTRAINT product_related_product
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES product (id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;

-- Table: feature
CREATE TABLE feature (
    id bigserial  NOT NULL,
    name text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT feature_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Table: product_features
CREATE TABLE product_features (
    product_id int8  NOT NULL,
    feature_id int8  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_features_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id,feature_id)
);

CREATE INDEX product_features_idx_1 on product_features (product_id ASC);

CREATE INDEX product_features_idx_2 on product_features (feature_id ASC);

-- Reference: product_features_feature (table: product_features)
ALTER TABLE product_features ADD CONSTRAINT product_features_feature
    FOREIGN KEY (feature_id)
    REFERENCES feature (id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;

-- Reference: product_features_product (table: product_features)
ALTER TABLE product_features ADD CONSTRAINT product_features_product
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES product (id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;
```

Full code generated by SQLacodegen:

```py
t_product_features = Table(
    'product_features', metadata,
    Column('product_id', ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('feature_id', ForeignKey('feature.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
)


t_product_related = Table(
    'product_related', metadata,
    Column('product_id', ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True),
    Column('related_id', ForeignKey('related.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
)

class Feature(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'feature'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('feature_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    products = relationship('Product', secondary='product_features')


class Related(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'related'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('related_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    mpn = Column(Text)
    title = Column(Text)
    price = Column(Float)
    msrp = Column(Float)
    stock_availability = Column(Boolean)
    country_id = Column(ForeignKey('country.id'), index=True)
    description = Column(Text)
    weight_packaging = Column(Float)
    item_type = Column(String(20))
    upc = Column(String(40))
    model = Column(String(60))
    sku = Column(String(40))
    badges = Column(Text)
    url = Column(Text)
    site_item_id = Column(Text)
    brand_id = Column(ForeignKey('brand.id'), index=True)

    brand = relationship('Brand')
    country = relationship('Country')
    relateds = relationship('Related', secondary='product_related')
```

What I would expect SQLacodegen's output to look like:

```py
t_product_features = Table(
    'product_features', metadata,
    Column('product_id', ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('feature_id', ForeignKey('feature.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
)


t_product_related = Table(
    'product_related', metadata,
    Column('product_id', ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True),
    Column('related_id', ForeignKey('related.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
)

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    mpn = Column(Text)
    title = Column(Text)
    price = Column(Float)
    msrp = Column(Float)
    stock_availability = Column(Boolean)
    country_id = Column(ForeignKey('country.id'), index=True)
    description = Column(Text)
    weight_packaging = Column(Float)
    item_type = Column(String(20))
    upc = Column(String(40))
    model = Column(String(60))
    sku = Column(String(40))
    badges = Column(Text)
    url = Column(Text)
    site_item_id = Column(Text)
    brand_id = Column(ForeignKey('brand.id'), index=True)

    brand = relationship('Brand')
    country = relationship('Country')
    relateds = relationship('Related', secondary='product_related')
    features = relationship('Feature', secondary='product_feature')

class Feature(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'feature'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('feature_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class Related(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'related'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('related_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but per definition Parent Child relation are one to many and not many to many

Comment: @NirElbaz thank you for the clarification. However, my issue is still that I want to have both, relateds and features under the product. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent-child relationship is determined based on the order of table names in the database. The table names are alphabetically sorted in the database. In this instance, the `Product` is coming before `Related`, therefore, the `Product` is the parent of `Related`. However, since `Feature` comes before `Product`, the former is bein defined as the parent of the latter.